# Not getting all the rows in top and bottom filter in AWS quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using top and bottom filter to show top 10 rows and country filter control but got less rows as expected every time i changed country by country control and dataset contain more then 50 rows for each country.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and for me it was because of a QuickSight limit of Top 50 when using the Vertical stacked bar chart visualisation. If you change your visualisation to e.g. Line chart the restriction goes away.